# Ionic run fail to deploy to device

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Mac OS X 10.11. I am trying to deploy build to device (iPhone 4) by running `sudo ionic run ios --device` and I get this error message:

```
Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/john/Desktop/Myproject/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,Myproject.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64,-target,Myproject,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/john/Desktop/Myproject/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/john/Desktop/Myproject/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/john/Desktop/Myproject/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I have no problem when running just only `ionic run ios`, which will deploy the app into emulator. How can I overcome the problem?

Comment: Nope that did not fix. That is not the fix to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method will be

Go to your platform directory of your project `/platforms/ios`

Write in the console `open .` which will open your folder with Finder.

After that open `YourProject.xcodeproj` with **XCode** and select your device and click on run.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my project wasn't created using xcode. How can I make my project into xcode?

Comment: @user1995781 Yes but when you use Ionic / Cordova / Phonegap they create a native part (part which can be used with XCode) for you. 

So even if you don't write in XCode files directly they are in your folder (/platform/ios)

See my first answer, it will works I thinks

Comment: @NapstersDesmars Thanks a lot for your great help. Tried, it works. But everytime I have to run `sudo ionic build ios` first then run on xcode again to get it deploy to the device. Is there easier & faster way to do it? Or it would be great if can make the command work directly. Thank you.

Comment: @user1995781I don't thinks that is possible because you need copy all files update in the applications and after that the compiler (xcode) create your application and deploy on the emulator or your device.

Maybe it's possible but I don't thinks that easy.

Good luck

Comment: This worked great, thanks. This method allows XCode to automatically fix the identity. It should prompt you to choose the signing profile you'd like to use.